# Crawling 500 for not existing URL's

Tags: javascript, performance, web-crawler, internal-server-error, google-crawlers

Google crawl throws server errors for pages that do not exist, which are linked from pages that do not exist.

example:

http://www.dailyforex.com/forex-technical-analysis/forex-blog-reviews/page-506
Which linked from:
http://www.dailyforex.com/forex-technical-analysis/forex-blog-reviews/page-504

This URL's structure and pagination never exist on our site!
Does anyone know where these links are coming and how to fix it?

I have a lot of links like that, please help me solve it!

tnx,
Lena

Comment: Lots of reasons they might crawl url's that don't exist. You should be concerned more about why it causes a 500 server error

Answer (score 0):

It is coming from a script

```
// visitorlp - The user first landing page
googletag.pubads().setTargeting("visitorlp", "http://www.dailyforex.com/forex-technical-analysis/forex-blog-reviews/page-506");
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining. Is it your script? Or where did you find that? Otherwise, why do you think that this is the source?

Comment: @Thomas it is not my script. It is a line of a script that is included in the page. It is related to some configuration done for Google GPT. You can find it with developer console of your browser.

Comment: @JoséPaiva what about this link :http://www.dailyforex.com/forex-fundamental-analysis/eur-usd-forecast/page-83 it also have link from page-82/page-85 but not google tag is mention in the source.

Comment: Well after we check it its not google issue and still a mystery